# Android widget for selecting between options

Tags: android, widget

I'm new to android and I want to have a widget like below . I'm using api level 10.
[image]

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Go With TabActivity see the tutorial [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I don't think this is what I want. I just want tabs to select between 3 options and just get a number as output to determine which one selected. Just that no more activities or stuff... is it possible??

Comment: Then It's Quite Easy Just Create Those Images in Photoshop or with the Help of graphic designer and just create three buttons with Background as specific drawables and write click listener for each button

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used OnTouchListener to respond touch event on my button and according to the touched place I changed the background of my button.